# Handling parallel nested observables in RxJS

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I'm working on cleaning up nested parallel observables in my project and I am having some issues wrapping my head around handling the observable events. Here's one situation in my music application where I load the Playlist page and need to load the playlist data, information about the user, and if the user is following the playlist:

---

- Route Observable (**returns** parameters from URL, I need to extract the `playlistId`)

  - Playlist Observable (needs `playlistId` and **returns** `PlaylistObject` and resolves)
  - User Observable (**returns** `UserObject`)

    - IsUserFollowing Observable (needs `playlistId` and `UserObject.id` and **returns** T/F if user is following the playlist)

---

In summary, I receive the route parameter from Angular's `Route` observable, I need to fire two other observables in parallel, the `Playlist Observable` and `User Observable`. The `Playlist Observable` can resolve once the playlist data is returned, but the `User Observable` needs to continue on to another observable, `IsFollowingUser`, until it can resolve.

Here is my current (bad) implementation with nested observables:

```
this.route.params.pipe(
  first()
).subscribe((params: Params) => {

  this.playlistId = parseInt(params["playlistId"]);

  if (this.playlistId) {

    this.playlistGQL.watch({ 
      id: this.playlistId,
    }).valueChanges.pipe(
      takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe)
    ).subscribe((response) => { 
      this.playlist = response; // use this to display playlist information on HTML page
      this.playlistTracks = response.tracks; //loads tracks into child component
    });

    this.auth.user$.pipe(
      filter(stream => stream != null)
    ).subscribe((user) => {
      this.user = user;
      this.userService.isFollowingPlaylist(this.user.id, this.playlistId).subscribe((response) => {
        this.following = response; //returns a T/F value that I use to display a follow button
      })
    })

  }
```

This works but obviously does not follow RxJS best practices. What is the best way to clean up nested parallel observables like this?

Answer (score 0):

This is something I would do although this may not be the most optimal but could be better than before.

I will assume the previous code block is in an `ngOnInit`.

```
async ngOnInit() {
  // get the params as if it is a promise
  const params: Params = await this.route.params.pipe(
                                      first()
                                    ).toPromise();

  this.playlistId = parseInt(params["playlistId"]);
  if (this.playlistId) {
    // can name these functions to whatever you like (better names)
    this.reactToPlaylistGQL();
    this.reactToUser();
  }
}

private reactToPlaylistGQL() {
  this.playListGQL.watch({
    id: this.playListId,
  }).valueChanges.pipe(
   takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe)
 ).subscribe(response => {
   this.playlist = response;
   this.playlistTracks = response.tracks;
 });
}

private reactToUser() {
  this.auth.user$.pipe(
    filter(stream => stream != null),
    // switch over to the isFollowingPlaylist observable
    switchMap(user => {
     this.user = user;
     return this.userService.isFollowingPlaylist(this.user.id, this.playListId);
   }),
    // consider putting a takeUntil or something of that like to unsubscribe from this stream
  ).subscribe(response => this.following = response);
}
```

I find naming the functions in the `if (this.playlistId)` block to human friendly names makes it unnecessary to write comments (the descriptive function name says what it should do) and looks cleaner than putting a blob of an RxJS stream.

I wrote this all freehand so there might be some typos.